# how to load data in angular $http.get in while loop and stop the loop from within the success snipet

Tags: angularjs, http, asynchronous

/*Hi. I have a server which returns array of data in chunks of 1000. I do not know the total length of it before the load. I would like to load the array in $http.get:
however, it runs forever. what to do?*/

```
var load_end = false;
var url = "/some_array.json?";
var page_num = 1;
$scope.vars = [];
do{
var new_url = url+'page_num='+page_num;
$http.get(new_url).success(function(data){
if(!data.length){
load_end = true//loading ended
}
$scope.vars = $scope.vars.concat(data); 
page_num++;
})
}while(!load_end);
```

Comment: Put the `$http` call in a function, and if you need to keep loading more, recall the function in the success call. Right now I imagine that `while` loop is sending off a TON of requests.

Comment: Can you let your server send the number of needed requests in the first result? Then you could send exactly that amount of requests in paralellel. Else you would need to go with what @tymeJV said and send those requests after each other.

Comment: about the first, that sounds good. recursive. about the 2nd, if I had that, I wouldn't be needing any help about it cause then the number of calls would be exactly up to that number.